# Custom `stylelint` plugin for `styled-components`

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, stylelint

I have been trying to build a new custom `stylelint` plugin for `styled-components` after [following the instructions here](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins).

The requirement is to build a custom `stylelint` plugin, where I want to prevent users from specifying hardcoded values present in `styled-components` in favor of using values that should be read from a common design file.

```
// Incorrect usage
const Header = styled.div`
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
`;


// Correct usage
import {FONT, COLOR} from 'constants';

const Header = styled.div`
  font-size: ${FONT.M};
  color: ${COLOR.PRIMARY};
`;
```

I found that the [stylelint-processor-styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/stylelint-processor-styled-components) is supposed to act as a
processor for our `styled-components`. However, I am unable to find any documentation or way which can help me adding a processor to my custom plugin.

Any help here, can be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `stylelint-processor-styled-components` in .stylelintrc file as:

```
{"processors": [
"stylelint-processor-styled-components"
 ]}
```

After that, you can just add the rules for linting given on official stylelint documentation for static values prevention i.e.

```
"rules": {
    "length-zero-no-unit":true,
    "color-no-hex": true,
    "color-named": [
        "never",
        {
            "message": "Static color name"
        }
    ]}
```